# Reactjs : I want to show component when click button but this work only time

Tags: reactjs

I want to show component when click button but this work  only time how fix it

```
<Invoice item={billdetails}  />

<button onClick={ () => getBillDetails(item) }>show</button>

const Invoice = (item ) => {
    const Theme = useContext(ThemeContext);
    const [bill, setBill] = useState([]);

    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        getAllBill();
        setShow(!open);
    }, [item ]);

    const getAllBill = async () => {
        let response = await allBills(item.item._id);
        setBill(response.data);
        console.log(response.data);
        console.log('iaad', bill);
    }

    return (
        <div className="invoice">
            {
                bill._id && ReactDOM.createPortal(<div id="form__add">
                    <div className="backdrop" onClick={() => { setBill([]); setShow(!show)  }} > </div>

                    {/* // bill  customer: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Customer', }, products: [ { product: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product', }, quantity: { type: Number, default: 0 }, price: { type: Number, default: 0 }, discountRate: { type: Number, default: 0 }, total: { type: Number, default: 0 } } ], total: { type: Number, default: 0 }, discountRate: { type: Number, default: 0 }, discount: { type: Number, default: 0 }, netTotal: { type: Number, default: 0 }, paid: { type: Number, default: 0 }, due: { type: Number, default: 0 }, paymentMethod: { type: String, default: "Cash" }, status: { type: String, default: "Pending" } */}
                    <div className="invoice__header">
                        <div className="invoice__header__left">
                            <h1>Invoice</h1>
                            <p>Invoice No: {bill._id}</p>
                            <p>Invoice Date: {bill.createdAt}</p>
                            <p>paymentMethod {bill.paymentMethod} </p>
                            <p>
                                <span>Customer Name: {bill.customer && bill.customer.name}</span>
                                <span>Customer Phone: {bill.customer && bill.customer.phone}</span>
                            </p>
                            <table>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Product</th>
                                        <th>Quantity</th>
                                        <th>Price</th>
                                        <th>Total</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    {bill.products && bill.products.map((item, index) => (
                                        <tr key={index}>
                                            <td>{item.name}</td>
                                            <td>{item.quantity}</td>
                                            <td>{item.price}</td>
                                            <td>{item.quantity * item.price}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    ))}
                                </tbody>

                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>, document.getElementById('modal'))
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: in useEffect change  [item]  to  [item.item._id], will this work

Comment: don't work after changed  [item] to [item.item._id],

Comment: try changing const Invoice = (item ) to const Invoice = ({ item })

Comment: don't work again

Comment: I think it will be better to create a minimal codesandbox example or put more code on the question

Comment: Your Invoice seems to be a modal or conditionally rendered component. You can move all the state variables in the Invoice to its parent and render data only through props inside the Invoice. Also, you can fetch your bills before showing the Invoice to the user or show some loader to the user till the bills are retrieved.